# Bootstrap 3 - Trouble Vertically Aligning Input Group Button and Form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sort of a weird problem. I'm following [this section](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) exactly but having a little trouble. When the button is aligned to the left of the field they align perfectly but when the button is aligned to the right (which I think of as more natural for a "submit" type behavior) there is about 5-10px of padding on top of the button that I can't get rid of:

[image: Demonstration of the problem]

My code is below:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
   <h3>Get the latest Amazon News first:</h3>
   <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-default btn-group" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </span>
   </div><!-- /input-group -->
</div><!-- /col-7 -->
<div class="col-sm-5">
   <h3>Get Started Now:</h3>
   <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#"><i class="icon-caret-right icon-space-right"></i>Start a Free Trial!</a>
</div>
```

I'm pretty confused why it would work on one side and not the other.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you add some extra styling to your code? Because it [looks pretty nice for me](http://jsfiddle.net/4Gs8Z/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems to be wrong if you have written any of your custom css. I just copied your html and created a pen using bootstrap cdn css hosted files. [Check this pen/demo.](http://cdpn.io/mhucz)

It's because somehow you are adding break tag i.e. 
 above and below of your button element. just remove those breaks.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for looking into this. I combed my custom CSS and can't find anything, but I agree it must be something I've set in there. Inspector doesn't show any custom classes applied to it but I'll keep digging

Comment: @JeffW just copy all the code from my demo and then try running on ur system.

Comment: @JeffW It's because somehow you are adding break tag i.e. `<br/>` above and below of your button element. just remove those breaks.

Comment: Thanks! I saw those just now. I have no idea where they are coming from :/ but I'll zero in on that.

Comment: @JeffW I have updated the answer, you may vote that as an answer for you if you wish.